# Firebase Realtime Database long values always return 0 even though it is not

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to search for a solution for quite some time, but to no avail. I am clearly not a Firebase expert and am still learning how to code.

I am currently creating a log-in system where, on top of the e-mail verification system that Firebase provides, there is another layer of authentication that I manually have to do myself. Thus, to achieve this, I introduced Firebase Realtime Database into my project. Here is a snippet of the JSON file in the database.

```
{
 "users" : {
  "abfkbnqeiurbnafjbnaojn" : {
   "app_authorized" : 1,
   "email" : "example51245@gmail.com",
   "full_name" : "Test Sample",
   "user_id" : "abfkbnqeiurbnafjbnaojn"
  }
 }
}
```

As you can see from the JSON file, the app_authorized key-value pair will govern whether the user can sign-in or not (0 means the user is not eligible while 1 means the user is eligible to sign-in). I am using the user's UID from Firebase's sign-in with e-mail and password system for the parent for all key-value pairs. I am also aware that the value type for app_authorized is long.

Here is the code that I used in my SignInActivity.

```
long isAppAuthorized;

//some codes here

private void init() {

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: attempting to log in");

                String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

                //validates respective EditTexts
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {

                    emailEditText.setError("Please fill in your e-mail address!");

                }
                else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {

                    passwordEditText.setError("Please fill in your password!");

                } else {

                    progressDialog.show();

                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(SignInActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

                                    userID = user.getUid();

                                    final DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("users/" + userID + "/app_authorized");

                                    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            //gets value of isAppAuthorized
                                            isAppAuthorized = dataSnapshot.getValue(long.class);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });

                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                                    } else {

                                        try {
                                            //this is the part where I check for both isEmailVerified and isAppAuthorized
                                            if(user.isEmailVerified() && isAppAuthorized == 1) {

                                                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: success. e-mail is verified " + user.isEmailVerified() + " userIsAuthorized: " + isAppAuthorized);
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);

                                            } else {

                                                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: failed: isEmailVerified: " + user.isEmailVerified() + " userIsAuthorized: " + isAppAuthorized);

                                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                mAuth.signOut();
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);

                                            }

                                        } catch(NullPointerException e) {

                                            Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage());

                                        }
                                    }

                                    // ...
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

The problem that I encountered is that the isAppAuthorized long always returns 0 regardless of what value I put into the database, thus, rendering my second layer of authorization useless.

I hope that someone is able to help me with this as I have tried many things and am still unable to understand the source of the problem.

Comment: Try   `isAppAuthorized = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);`

Comment: This worked out after I changed both the variable declaration and long.class to Long with the capital L (it returned a NullException error though). Is there a reason why I must use Long instead of long?

Comment: Long is an reference to an object while long is a primitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
isAppAuthorized = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
```

Comment: with reference to Tarun's comment, I tried this as well. It also worked (but gave a NullException error at first). Is this because int and long cannot return a null reference compared to Integer and Long?

Thank you for the help, I will try to resolve the NullException error.

Comment: @applejuice  dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class); you need to pass class (Long is a class) but long is not a class

Comment: @applejuice you can get null if app_authorized doesnot exist check your database from firebase console

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification!